# How to identify an application run in server using url

Tags: tcp

How can we identify an application running on a server using a url? What will be included in the url to identify the application? Is it the IP address of the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to identify what applications a server is running (or serving) based on just the URL, it isn't that simple.

A single server could be running zero, one, or many applications. Additionally, not all applications running on a server will be accessible via HTTP. Therefore, not all applications can be identified via URL.

URLs tend to represent the file/routing structure on a web server. Your best guess at what application is running on a server, solely based on URL, would be to reference the fully qualified domain name (FQDN). The FQDN may hint about what the web server you are utilizing may be intended for.

Comment: Do you have any other questions regarding this topic?  If you are satisfied with the provided response please mark the question as answered.